# How can I deploy J2EE application in tomcat 7.0?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have write a simple J2EE application. I have used Eclipse JUNO, Tomcat 7.0.
I have import into my workspace a simple web app. It works. Now I have apple the change at Home page, but when I try to run server. I don't see my change.
I know that I must do a deploy but I don't Know how I can do it.

Comment: How have You deployed the application for the first time? What is the change? A simple change to a JSP view, html? Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Window -> Show View -> Servers
```

On server you can make restart.

Your app have to be on server so right click on server "Add and Remove" and add your app to the server.

Redeploy is needed only if you make change in backend (or backing bean) every changes in .xhtml will appear automatically after page refresh.

Comment: I have the View Servers, I have apply right click on it, add remove program, then I have selected my progeject and then I have run in debug. Works. But now I try to change index.html into index2.html and restart the server. So I see the same result. And if I try to get this link in my browser I see Error 404. tHE LINK IS: http://localhost:8080/test-app/index2.html

Comment: You should use index2.jsf   JSF(or xhtml) not html